# I still don't understand the explanation about How does one play music when both hands are to play the same notes?]

Tags: chords

[[image]
I've read the previous posts on how to do this and don't understand in this situation how to play them when both hands are to play the same note. Please help by explaining very simply

Comment: What instrument(s) is this music for? Are both clefs supposed to be for the same instrument?

Comment: @Dekkadeci - isn't that why there's a bracket holding both parts together? It's surely piano.

Comment: Could you please add the source of this piece?

Answer (score 4):

Well, the easy way of course is to play this on an instrument with two manuals, like an organ or harpsichord or free bass accordion or bandonion.

The next "easiest" way on a piano is to play this two-handed (staggering the hands a bit so that the right hand may move across the left hand), use a pedal on each beat and only strike the left hand notes briefly into the pedal in order to be able to play the right hand phrases with the right hand.

Without pedalling, you can do a "left-hand pedal" by releasing the keys not far enough for the notes to dampen but far enough that you may restrike with the right hand.

Playing this right-hand only on the accordion (definitely nicer to use a chromatic button accordion here to avoid stretches) is what I find most mentally draining: basically you *think* of holding the "left-hand" notes steady but give them a very brief respite when the "right-hand" notes walk across them.  In this case the same fingers are getting used but the melody articulation "walks across them".

That kind of mess happens sometimes in Bach keyboard fugues: where you have just a single manual available for multiple voices, you may have a non-rigid voice distribution across hands and fingers.  You then need to think more in terms of what the keys have to do rather than the fingers: the keys are what carries the melody, making use of whatever finger or hand happens to be in the vicinity.

While the thought is soothing that this may have been written for two instruments or two manuals or different octaves, the progression of difficulty may point to this being written for the explicit purpose of exercising this kind of mental contortion.

Answer (score 1):

This question is too problematic to completely answer.  The answer would depend on the instrument it is meant for and you need to specify that.  Since both staves are treble I am going to "assume" it's guitar music.

Based on the assumption...

You are not supposed to play both as this looks like duet music.
Having said that, if you want to rearrange it for solo guitar that may be possible (I didn't go that deep) but you may need to make some sacrifices with respect to the chord notes if they are not easy to play.

Comment: This is not guitar music Solo guitar music is written on one staff (treble.) One voice would have stems going up and a second voice would have stems going down. If it was for two guitars, the two staves would be surrounded by  a bracket, not a brace.

Comment: @HeatherS., I have an extensive collection of classical guitar music including duets.  They are printed exactly as the example in the OP (surrounded by a brace).  I do not believe that the various prints are all wrong.  The OP was confusing and ambiguous.  Also, it is not uncommon for guitar music to have doubled notes (a fingered note and an open string unison companion) hence even the title "...both hands are to play the same notes?" is unclear.

Comment: yes I get that guitar music can play the same note doubled, as guitar like all strings (and unlike piano) has options to play the same pitch in different places. I find it odd that the music would be braced instead of bracketed, but I guess I learn something every day.  My son and daughter are both classical guitarists.  I have never seen a solo piece written on two lines.  The OP's music selection does not make sense on piano.

Comment: I didn't say solo.  My answer mentioned duets.  Duets are bracketed as piano music.  Solo never, to voices as you say with stems in different directions.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a piano piece, then the answer is simple.  You release the left hand notes once they have been played in order to make the (mainly) 'f' notes available in the right hand.  Use the pedal to make the left hand notes sound more sustained.

Comment: If it's a piano piece, then the fourth bar is horrendous. Both clefs have D's and F's that I'm (supposedly) expected to hold down and re-strike. Uggghhhhh, I can't believe I'm reading this sheet music (unless at least one clef is not for piano).

Comment: The forth bar is fine.  Since you are already playing the Ds in the right hand, you needn't play them in the left.  Pedalling will give the impression of the left hand dotted crotchet length Ds.